# Масштабирование нарисованых объектов

Tags: c#

Есть нарисованный на `panel` [image: рисунок]

Вот код отрисовки:

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     Graphics gPanel = panel1.CreateGraphics();
     Pen b = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
     //Вертикальные линии
     for (int x = 0; x < 475; x += 25)
     {
         for(int y = 0; y < 475; y += 25)
         {
             gPanel.DrawLine(b, x, y, x + 100, y );
         }
     }
     //Горизонтальные линии
     for (int x = 0; x < 575; x += 25)
     {
         for (int y = 0; y < 475; y += 25)
         {
             gPanel.DrawLine(b, x, y, x, y + 100);
         }
     }
     Pen r = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         PrintTringle(gPanel, r, x, y, x + (25 * 8), y, x + (25 * 4), y + (25 * 4));
         y += (25 * 2);
         x += (25 * 1);

         PrintTringle(gPanel, r, x, y, x + (25 * 6), y, x + (25 * 3), y + (25 * 3));

         tmpX = x + (25 * 6);
         tmpY = y;

         y += (25 * 2);
         x += (25 * 1);
         PrintTringle(gPanel, r, x, y, x + (25 * 4), y, x + (25 * 2), y + (25 * 2));

         x = tmpX;
         y = tmpY;
     }
 }
```

Как при масштабировании формы, изменять размер `panel`, а так же нарисованный внутри рисунок? Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не используйте ручное рисование, используйте Path, он как раз для этого предназначен.

Comment: @VladD можно поподробнее про Path

Comment: @Log1c0 [какие](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/17.2.php) [именно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) [подробности](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level13/13_1.php) вам нужны?

Comment: Раз уж вы используете WinForms... У класса `Graphics` есть метод `ScaleTransform` - перед отрисовкой вызываете его с нужным вам масштабом. Масштаб рассчитываете вручную (простая пропорция) в событии изменения размеров формы (`Resize`/`SizeChanged`).